# bison precedence is useless? it doesn't work

Tags: c, bison, operator-precedence

I have declared such precedence for `bison` :

```
    %left '+' '-'
    %left '*' '/'
```

Recursive rules for arithmetic:

```
exp:       exp binary_op exp { .. }
           | literal_exp     { .. }
           | ID              { .. }

binary_op: '+'               { .. }
           | '-'             { .. }
           | '*'             { .. }
           | '/'             { .. }
```

I have an arithmetic expression: `10 * 3 + 5`

My program calculates the sum, and it's 80! I still don't know why precedence doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work if you define the expressions like this:

```
exp:       exp '+' exp       { .. }
           exp '-' exp       { .. }
           exp '*' exp       { .. }
           exp '/' exp       { .. }
           | literal_exp     { .. }
           | ID              { .. }
```

The precedence only works when the operators are present as terminals in the rule.

See the documentation on [How precedence works](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/bison_8.html#SEC75):

> each rule gets its precedence from the last terminal symbol mentioned
>   in the components

Your rule for exp has no terminals, hence no precedence is applied.